# Microbiome Data

Tags: genetics, bioinformatics, genomics, microbiome

How is it possible to access microbiome data like that found [here](http://www.exploredata.net/Downloads/Microbiome-Data-Set)? I'd like to perform analyses on similar type of data, but cannot find OTU data like that at the [Human Biome Project](http://commonfund.nih.gov/hmp/). Thanks for any leads.

Comment: Purely computational questions are better suited for http://biostars.org

Answer (score 3):

This .csv files (comma-separated value) can be imported into Galaxy ([usegalaxy.org](http://usegalaxy.org))

I recommend that you take a look at that web app, it has many build in applications for analysis.

Also this site has a lot of quick video tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll check it out. My goal was to get OTU prevalence data (like at the exploredata.net site) and not just the Human Biome Data (regardless of format [e.g., csv, FASTA,etc.]) on what constitutes a particular OTU.

Answer (score 2):

The data that you are pointing to are files in .csv (comma-separated value) format. They can be opened, after downloading, by any standard spreadsheet programme, including Excel, as well as programmatically (e.g. in Python using the csv module)

Apologies if you understood this and were asking for something more.